# rb plugin the hot key not working

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, rhythmbox

```
def activate(self,shell):
        self.shell = shell
        self.action = gtk.Action ('foo','bar','baz',None)
        self.activate_id = self.action.connect ('activate', self.call_bk_fn,self.shell)
        self.action_group = gtk.ActionGroup ('hot_key_action_group')
        self.action_group.add_action_with_accel (self.action, "<control>E")

        uim = shell.get_ui_manager ()
        uim.insert_action_group (self.action_group, 0)
        uim.ensure_update ()
def call_bk_fn(self,shell):
                print('hello world')
```

i am using the above code in a plugin for rhythmbox ,and here i am trying to register the key ctr+e so that the call_bk_fn gets called whenever the key combination is pressed , but its not working why is that so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that i did remark is that your callback should be like this:

```
def call_bk_fn(self, event, shell):
    print('hello world')
```

hope this can help :), if you still have some problem i think you should give us more info about the errors that are raised  .

Comment: @singularity , i changed that but that didn't work :( , i am not getting any output/error msg :(

Comment: @Bunny Rabbit: run rb using this command __rhythmbox -D filter__ now all the error should be displayed to your terminal; add the errors displayed to your question if you can see them . hope it can help :)

Comment: @singularity i was already using it , and no i can't see any errors , and in case u are suspected if the plugin is active or not , i tested that too with a couple of print statements and found they are getting printed..

Comment: @Bunny Rabbit: i still don't understand how your first code didn't raise any error that can be outputed because the __self.call_bk_fn__ callback didn't exist because you have defined the function __call_bk_fn__ without __self__ !!!! BTW i just edited my answer by adding another parameter to the callback after all it's much near of gtk callbacks way try it like this, if it's not working you can try without the keyboard event something like in this example:  http://www.kryogenix.org/code/RBMicroBlog/RBMicroBlog.tar.gz because i have a hint that the problem is in the keyboard event accelerator.

Comment: @Bunny Rabbit: no but this line __connect ('activate', self.call_bk_fn...)__   should raise an error in the later code because there is not such __self.call_bk_fn__ you see what i mean ? i think it will be great for you if you can see the error that are raised somehow, and rb is not showing them i think , so there is no way to find out errors maybe i'm mistaken because you told me that you can see debug prints !!!